# Azure HDInsight MapReduce AdditionalInputPath is ignored

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to run map/reduce job where the input path only includes certain folders in a date hierachy ordered directory.

Without the ability to use any decent sort of regex on the input path, the 'additionalInputPath' seemed like a winner.

Problem is, the job seems to ignore the additional input path and only runs on the original input path.

Anybody come across this / have any suggestions? Is there a better way of restricting the inputPath to "/input/2014/08/*/*" and "/input/2014/09/*/*" (ie ignore "/input/2014/01/*/*" through "/input/2014/07/*/*")

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce;

namespace AdHocAnalysis.Sessions 
{
    class Job : HadoopJob<Mapper, Reducer>
    {
        public override HadoopJobConfiguration Configure(ExecutorContext context)
        {
            HadoopJobConfiguration config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();
            config.InputPath = "/input/2014/08/*/*";
            config.AdditionalInputPath.Add("/input/2014/09/*/*");
            config.OutputFolder = "/output/jobOutput/";
            return config; 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is basically the same as the code that worked for me. I abandoned that approach because I was not getting values populated in MapperContext.InputFilename. My input files had different layouts, and I intended to interrogate context.InputFilename to determine how I show parse the incoming data.

That said, if the code snippet above accurately represents your situation, I think we can solve your problem without needing HadoopJobConfiguration.AdditionalInputPath. Hadoop will stream all the blobs within a folder hierarchy, without the need to specify wildcards.

If you want to map all the files in 2014, use the inputpath...

```
  config.InputPath = "/input/2014";
```

If you want a specific month, use the inputpath...

```
  config.InputPath = "/input/2014/08";
```

If you want only August and September, and AdditionalInputPath is not working, then you may be forced to temporarily copy the blobs you want to process into their own folder hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I do indeed want to look only at August and September but was hoping to avoid any duplication of data as we're looking at around the 50 Gb mark. Not to worry, I need to take a proper look at the data structure as it currently stands in the blob storage account anyway.